# MPMoviePlayerController Taking screen shot but showing only black screen

Tags: iphone

I taking screenshot when playing the MPMoviePlayerController.Perfectly save the screen shot but image is Only Black Color.I use Below code.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.moviePlayerController.view.frame.size);
[self.moviePlayerController.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, nil, nil, nil);
```

Answer (score 3):

Finally i fixed this Problem...I am using this code...Perfectly working...Thanks to all...

```
- (void)captureScreenShot
{
    CGImageRef originalImage = UIGetScreenImage();
    CGImageRef videoImage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(originalImage, CGRectMake(0, 66, 320, 230));            
    UIImage *snapShotImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:videoImage];
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(snapShotImage, nil, nil, nil);
    CGImageRelease(originalImage);                
    CGImageRelease(videoImage);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `thumbnailImageAtTime` method of `MPMoviePlayerController`.

```
UIImage *aThumbnail = [player thumbnailImageAtTime:timeCode timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionExact];
//timeCode is a time within the video length, for example: 5 seconds.
```

Comment: Thanks...But nothing happens     UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.moviePlayerController.view.frame.size);
    [self.moviePlayerController.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    
    UIImage *aThumbnail = [self.moviePlayerController thumbnailImageAtTime:0 timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionExact];

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(aThumbnail, nil, nil, nil);     I use this lines.