# Screenshot does not show the image in video

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I need to get the screenshot of a video on click of a button.Below is the code used for that,but the image shows only the bottom part of the video that is the play and progress with the time passed..I have used MPMoviePlayerController for the video to play.

```
CGRect rect = [_moviePlayer.view bounds];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[_moviePlayer.view.layer renderInContext:context];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

UIImageView   *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 100, 100)];
[imgView setImage:image];
imgView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
[_firstimage addSubview:imgView];
```

NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8"];

[image]

this is how it shows..How can i get the video image? Can anybody help me..

Comment: Check these two answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13855340/is-there-any-way-to-take-a-screenshot-when-mpmovieplayercontroller-is-playing or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11258765/mpmovieplayercontroller-taking-screen-shot-but-showing-only-black-screen

Comment: @Rog the second link helped..thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CGImageRef originalImage = UIGetScreenImage();
CGImageRef videoImage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(originalImage,   CGRectMake(0, 0, 680, 300));
UIImage *snapShotImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:videoImage];
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(snapShotImage, nil, nil, nil);
CGImageRelease(originalImage);
CGImageRelease(videoImage);
UIImageView   *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 250, 200)];
[imgView setImage:snapShotImage];
imgView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
[_firstimage addSubview:imgView];
```

this code works...thanks for the help...

Answer (score 0):

How about using [`[MPMoviePlayerController requestThumbnailImagesAtTimes:         timeOption:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MPMoviePlayerController/requestThumbnailImagesAtTimes:timeOption:)?